# How to only build, not run

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

In GoLand, how do I set up a Run/Debug Configuration to only build a project `go build` and not run it `go run *.go`.

The [Getting Started](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/getting-started-with-gogland.html#running) guide says *The Go Application type is equal to go build command* - but it actually runs my binary.

The [Features](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/features/) page doesn't offer any more details.

Up until now I've used Vim for editing, so I'm not familiar with any of JetBrain's GUI editors.

---

go version `go1.9 darwin/amd64`

Goland `Build #GO-172.3968.45, built on September 5, 2017`

Answer (score 12):

In the release (2017.3) version you may remove "Run after build" checkbox mark to prevent execution. 
[image: Checkbox position in run configuration dialog]

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not currently supported due to a number of reasons. You can vote / watch [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-2408) for updates.

If you want to have a workaround for this, you can define an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/external-tools.html) via Settings | Tools | External Tools that can be assigned a shortcut to and have it build either the current directory or the project directory. However, this might not be the ideal approach in some cases (which is why it's not yet present in the IDE by default).